# How to get cluster Id with WMI?

Tags: c#, c++, wmi, windows-clustering

There is cluster ID property that can be retrieved with `Get-Cluster | fl Id` powershell command. How to get it with WMI? Looks like  `MSCluster_Cluster` doesn't have ID field.